# character to use when splitting strings in visual c#?

Tags: c#, split

Ok, I'm racking my brains over this one.  It's pretty simple though (I think).

I'm currently creating a text file as a comma separated string of values.

Later, I read in that file data and then use the `.split` function to split the data by commas.

I discovered that sometimes one of the description fields in the data conatins an embedded comma, which ends up throwing the `split` command off.

Is there any special character I could use that could pretty much guarantee wouldn't be in the data, or is there a better way to accomplish this?  Thanks!

```
// Initial Load
fullString = fileName + "," + String.Join(",", fieldValues);

// Access later
String[] valuesArray = myString.Split(',');
```

Comment: A common thing to do in CSV files is to allow a value to be enclosed in quotation marks. Anything inside the quotation marks would not be parsed.

Comment: Find a free CSV parser library. Values with commas should be quoted. Once you're doing that, you need a proper parser. CSV is a simple, fun parser to write, but kids these days, mumble mumble, Herbert Hoover.

Comment: Another way of manipulating such text content use json convert serialize and serialize it

Comment: Try using *tabulation*, `"\t"`; however, there's no guarantee that data don't have the symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, there's no "simple" way to do it using Split. The best you can hope for is to set the deliminator as something cooky that wouldn't ever get used (but even that's not a guarantee).

The simple method would be to used something like CsvHelper (get it through Nuget) or any of the other dozen or so packages that are designed for parsing CSV.